# Z3 segmentation fault and non-numerical results

Tags: segmentation-fault, z3

I am completely scratching my head over why I'm getting segmentation faults when I ask `check-sat` for (what I think is) a fairly simple bit of SMT2 code I'm trying to run in Z3.

```
(declare-const A Int)
(declare-const B Int)
(declare-const C Int)
(declare-const D Int)
(assert (= A (or 2 3 5 7)))
(define-fun W ((In1 Int)) Int
    (ite (= In1 2) (or 3 5) 
        (ite (= In1 3) (or 5 7) 
            (ite (= In1 5) 7 
                (ite (= In1 7) 3 11)
            )
        )
    )
)
(assert (= B (W A)))
(assert (= C (W B)))
(assert (= D (W C)))
(declare-const MULT Int)
(assert (= MULT (* A B C D)))

; 210 because 210 = 2*3*5*7

(declare-const MODULUS Int)
(assert (= 0 (rem MULT 210)))
(assert (= MODULUS 0))
(echo "Check 1")
(check-sat)
(echo "Check 2")
(get-model)
```

The model seems happy enough to return a non-numerical model if I remove the `MODULUS` bit of the code, but what I was expecting was a numerical solution where A=2, B=3, C=5, D=7 (and the `MODULUS` bit to work).

```
(model 
(define-fun D () Int
(let ((a!1 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 5) 7 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 7) 3 11))))
(let ((a!2 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 2) (or 3 5)
(ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 3) (or 5 7) a!1))))
(let ((a!3 (ite (= a!2 3) (or 5 7) (ite (= a!2 5) 7 (ite (= a!2 7) 3 11)))))
(let ((a!4 (ite (= (ite (= a!2 2) (or 3 5) a!3) 7) 3 11)))
(let ((a!5 (ite (= (ite (= a!2 2) (or 3 5) a!3) 5) 7 a!4)))
(let ((a!6 (ite (= (ite (= a!2 2) (or 3 5) a!3) 3) (or 5 7) a!5)))
(ite (= (ite (= a!2 2) (or 3 5) a!3) 2) (or 3 5) a!6))))))))

(define-fun C () Int
(let ((a!1 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 5) 7 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 7) 3 11))))
(let ((a!2 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 2)(or 3 5)
(ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 3) (or 5 7) a!1))))
(let ((a!3 (ite (= a!2 3) (or 5 7) (ite (= a!2 5) 7 (ite (= a!2 7) 3 11)))))
(ite (= a!2 2) (or 3 5) a!3)))))

(define-fun B () Int
(let ((a!1 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 5) 7 (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 7) 3 11))))
(ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 2) (or 3 5) (ite (= (or 2 3 5 7) 3) (or 5 7) a!1))))

(define-fun A () Int
(or 2 3 5 7))
)
```

I've tried using different solvers, and I've tried using Reals and I tried fiddling with the settings for `model_evaluator` and `model` but I'm really not sure what I'm doing....

Has anyone else had any similar difficulties or any luck better debugging a seg fault (segmentation fault: 11, if it helps?!), or am I going outside the limitations of Z3 here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was likely caused by a bug in the type checking functions that was recently fixed, so this doesn't reproduce in the latest unstable version. The reason is that

```
(assert (= A (or 2 3 5 7)))
```

asserts that `A` (which is an `Int`) should be equal to `(or ...)` which is a `Bool`, so in the latest unstable version I get

```
(error "line 5 column 25: Sorts Int and Bool are incompatible")
```

(and more errors after that).

Comment: Aah, fantastic thank you - I hadn't realised. I've re-written and it now does as I wanted! Cheers!